# Change the format of a date

Tags: php, javascript

I submit a date through a form such as below

```
2012-07-24 17:50
```

but on the result page I want to change it's format and echo it to

```
Tuesday, 24 of July
```

How do I do this? Should I use PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: see [date()](http://www.php.net/date) and [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/strtotime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find PHP easier to work with:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d g:i", "2012-07-24 17:50");
echo $date->format("l, j of F");
```

Comment: Thank you for this, how can I have for example 24*th* or 3*rd* ?

Comment: Use the `S` modifier. See the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) manual for all formatting controls. `echo $date->format("l, jS of F");`

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = strtotime('2012-07-24 17:50');
echo date('l, j of F', $a);
```

More info http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

With php this would look like this:

```
echo date('l, d \\o\\f F', strtotime('2012-07-24 17:50'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use php, because javascript can be disabled.

You would do it like this

```
<?php
$dt = strtotime($_POST['posted_date']);
echo date('l, j \\o\\f F', $dt);
?>
```